# In DDD can the presentation layer use both the Repository and Service classes?

Tags: web-applications, architecture, domain-driven-design

If the presentation layer is only supposed to use services then, then service classes must expose the same methods that are already implemented by repositories just to make them available to the presentation layer.

This seems wrong. Can someone clarify it for me?

Comment: How many layers are we talking? Which ones do you have responsibility for developing?

Comment: I'm developing the whole application. To give you an idea, lets talk about a UI that upon loading of a blog post, increments the its view count. My repository would give me the blog entity and my service will increment the count. If my UI is supposed to only interact with the Service, then that service will have to expose a method which in turn calls my repository to get the blog. So the question is it correct for the UI to get the blog entity directly from the repository instead of the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is that it seems wrong because You don't actually need this level of abstraction.

Application services are [facades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Bad facade is one that adds more complexity than it resolves. Something like this:

```
public int Increment(int v){ v=v+1;return v;}
```

Unless it resolves complexity enough or You explicitly want everything to go through additional layer in order to decouple client as much as possible - it's useless.

Personally, I would just stick these things in controller (if MVC pattern is used):

```
public ActionResult ViewBlogPost(int id){
  //I like to name repositories as collections
  var blog=_blogs.Find(id);

  blog.IsBeingViewedBy(_currentViewer); 
  return View(blog);
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that you will avoid Domain Services all together?

Comment: @Am I'm talking about application services. Domain services are different things. But yeah, I try to avoid domain services cause need for domain service is a sign that model lacks aggregate root.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have "layer purity" - yes, that's the way to do it. But you can easily avoid having much redundant code. Make a `BaseService` that defines all common methods (like `save(..)`, `update(..)`, `delete(..)`). Other, more complex methods are likely to (and should) require some interaction with the domain object.

Btw, it is sometimes assumed that in DDD the repository layer is accessed from within the domain object. Although I think that's wrong, it is sometimes the case. If that's your case as well, then it's `service > domain object > repository`, and there can be no "shortcuts"