# Domain Driven Design- UI make direct call to Repository

Tags: domain-driven-design, dns

In domain driven design, is there any hard and fast rule that the UI layer should not make a call to the data access/repository layer? If not, then how should it work the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would handle calls to the Data Access Layer/Repository via an Application Layer (controller) which calls data access in the Infrastructure layer.

However, Ayende (of NHibernate fame) has some interesting points regarding this "rule."

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/23/night-of-the-living-repositories.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some people enjoy routing everything through application services. I personally dislike [that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573857/in-ddd-can-the-presentation-layer-use-both-the-repository-and-service-classes/4575856#4575856).

Only reason I see which could make "everything goes through services" approach sound reasonable to me is if You explicitly want it to be so in order to draw bold and strong line between client and domain model.

It's quite similar to using/avoiding repository pattern. Quoting Ayende:

> If you don’t want a LAYER/TIER boundary don’t have one just use nhibernate directly

It's that necessity of **seam** that should drive Your need of direct DA usage.
If You don't need that, You will end up adding heavy *noise*.

Answer (score 0):

No, no "hard and fast rule".

If it's a simple app you're building, just inject an ISession (or the like if you're not using NHibernate).

When things get more complex, I'd recommend you have a look at aggregate roots, repositories, and UI patterns such as MVVM, Passive View, and MVC.

"The correct way" depends on your context, and how you're planning to test.